# The process is gradually stabilizing vs the process is stabilizing gradually

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence in a university test: "the process....gradually", and I was supposed to fill the gap with either the present simple or the present continuous form of the verb "to stabilize". Without context I really didn't know which tense I had to use. I ended up using the present continuous tense because I thought it made a bit more sense. So, is it correct to say "The process is stabilizing gradually"? I do know that adverbs should be placed after the verb "to be", therefore from a grammatical standpoint "the process is gradually stabilizing" is probably the better sentence of the two. It seems to me, though, that in this case putting the adverb at the end of the sentence does not sound terrible.

Comment: Without context, one cannot say which verb-form is preferable. / The positioning of the adverb was possibly not part of the test (ie the intended choice could well be between (a) "the process g stabilizes g" and (b) "the process is g stabilizing g" where the positioning of the adverb is not a factor to be worried about. But one needs to ask the setter what they are actually looking for here. None of the four alternatives is ungrammatical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position of the adverb "substantially".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307591/position-of-the-adverb-substantially) The difference between *substantially contribute* and *contribute substantially* is essentially the same as that between *gradually stabilizing* and *stabilizing gradually* (i.e. - basically, *nothing*, unless you think the word you choose to present first gets a bit more "emphasis").